# Screen cuts off part of GRUB on boot

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I've recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Windows 7 desktop computer (on a seperate partition) Everything has gone smoothly except when I restart the computer and GRUB's loader screen shows, part of the screen gets cut off.. but once ive selected a boot option and hit enter, the screen readjusts to fill the entire monitor properly.

So my question is, is there a way I can correct this ? Kind of annoying not being able to see the full boot option

Comment: Hello Matthew, did you manage to find a solution. Did the answer by rjkrocks help out?

Answer (score 2):

Installing boot repair or start-up manager may solve your problem.. In these softwares there is an option to fix the resolution of GRUB.. All the best

[image: http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1322150524.png]

Either add ‘ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair’ to your Software Sources via the Software Centre or, for speeds-sake, add it using a new Terminal session:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

[image: Start-Up manager]

To install Start-up manager  do the following 
In a terminal, if the universe repository is enabled, run:

> > sudo apt-get install startupmanager

Source:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StartUpManager